# Renaming multiple files in folder

Tags: r, rename

```
  list.files()

  "file_iteration1_2019-03-01-03-38-16.csv"
  "file_iteration1_obs_2019-03-01-03-38-16.csv" 
  "file_iteration1_modp_2019-03-01-03-38-16.csv"
```

I want to rename these files without the year and time stamp so it looks like

```
"file_iteration1.csv"
"file_iteration1_obs.csv" 
"file_iteration1_modp.csv"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to rename the files in folder, you can combine `file.rename()` and `gsub()` (`sub()` or `stringr::str_remove()`, suggested by @avid_useR and @akrun, would also work fine). Try out:

```
file.rename(list.files(), gsub('_[0-9-]+', '', list.files()))
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sub`:

```
x <- c("file_iteration1_2019-03-01-03-38-16.csv", 
"file_iteration1_obs_2019-03-01-03-38-16.csv",
"file_iteration1_modp_2019-03-01-03-38-16.csv")

sub('_\\d{4}(-\\d{2}){5}', '', x)
# [1] "file_iteration1.csv"      "file_iteration1_obs.csv"  "file_iteration1_modp.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(files, "_[0-9-]+")
#[1] "file_iteration1.csv"      "file_iteration1_obs.csv"  "file_iteration1_modp.csv"
```